# Why don't I see the new company tree I added to phosphor-dbus-interfaces

Tags: openbmc

I added yaml files in phosphor-dbus-interfaces/com/cn and applied the changes (as a patch) to my openbmc build and I see that the server/client sources are generated in my build. And I see mapper running for the newspace. But I do not see the tree in busctl. Mapper processes on my system:

179 root      7648 S    phosphor-ldap-mapper

196 root      6264 S    mapperx --service-namespaces=com.cn xyz.openbmc_proj

237 root      3188 S    mapper wait /org/openbmc/control/power0

247 root      3188 S    mapper wait /xyz/openbmc_project/state/host0

This is my first time so I am sure I am missing some piece. Can someone tell me what I might be missing and confirm that I ought to see com/cn in the busctl tree? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something needs to now implement those interfaces. For example, a lot of the https://github.com/openbmc/phosphor-dbus-interfaces/tree/master/xyz/openbmc_project/State objects are implemented under the host-state manager application via:

https://github.com/openbmc/phosphor-state-manager/blob/master/host_state_manager.hpp#L27